# Find n from it's prime multiplicity factorization

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $n = \begin{equation*}
  \prod_{p \in P}^{} p^{v_p(n)}
\end{equation*}$ 
  be a positive integer such that for all p ∈ P we have $ν_p(n)$ ≤ 1. 
Moreover, $p \in P$
a prime p divides n if and only if p − 1 divides n, too. Compute n.

I came across with this example, but actually have no idea how even to start with it.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, note that $1 \mid n$ which forces $2\mid n$ since $2$ is prime. Then $3 \mid n$ since $3$ is prime.  This forces $6 \mid n$ and thus $7 \mid n$ since $7$ is prime.  Can you take this further?

EDIT: Here is the earlier problem that I couldn't locate before: [Prove that there exist infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $p\mid n$ iff $p-1\mid n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819103/prove-that-there-exist-infinitely-many-natural-numbers-n-such-that-p-mid-n-i/)

The criterion is almost identical but it doesn't require $n$ to be squarefree, which yields a few additional solutions.  That problem asks to prove there are infinitely many, but no progress was made on that front.  On the other hand, of the 4 known examples only one is squarefree.

Comment: No, not really. I do not understand these type of exercises so good. Can you help me by going a bit further?

Comment: @user3417419 I can't make it more clear with such a vague description as "I do not understand these type of exercises".  What is it that you don't understand about the exercise?  (By the way, it would be a very difficult exercise to prove that there is only one solution, but I suspect they are only looking for *some* solution.)

Comment: Wong, since we have an infinite set of prime numbers, I still don't get it how we can compute n. Should we stop at a point?

Comment: @user3417419 That is why I said it would be hard to prove there is only one solution. But to validate a single candidate $n$, you only need to check those primes for which $p$ or $p-1$ divide $n$, and those are finite in number since $p\le n+1$.

Comment: But eventually the process will terminate, even if it isn’t clear that it will.  For instance, we know that $14 \mid n$ but neither $14$ nor $15$ is prime so this does not force any new restrictions on $n$.

Comment: And as far as I see, you assume all $v_p(n)$ to be all 1?

Comment: @user3417419 That’s just a contorted way to express the notion that $n$ is squarefree.  Obviously the only possible values for $v_p(n)$ are $0$ or $1$ with the given constraints.  I certainly don’t assume that $v_p(n)=1$ for the infinitely many primes that **don’t** divide $n$.